# rails 4 Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following serializer

In my image table i have the data with id - 1,2,3,4

If i pass id in my serializer as 5 instead of throwing empty result it is throwing exception as

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Why does this occurs and how can i resolve it.

```
def image_ids
  image_id = Images.where(post_id: id).first
  unless image_id.nil?
    image_id = image_id.id
    [image_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: `Images.where(post_id: id).first` is nil, thats all

Comment: @apneadiving Sorry i couldn't get you..

Comment: He meant that your database query didn't yield any results. You cannot get the id of nothing. You first need to check if the query has any results and then you can return the id, otherwise return nothing (nil)

Comment: can you please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 --` because

`Images.where(post_id: id)` return `[]` for `id = 5` and if you do `[].first` then output will be `nil`

So, till this point your `image_id` is `nil`

Now when you do `nil`.id , it throws exception and since `nil.object_id happens to be 4`, it warns as stated.

For more information regarding this exception you can refer this blog : http://blog.bigbinary.com/2008/06/23/why-the-id-of-nil-is-4-in-ruby.html

You method should be :

```
def image_ids
  image_object = Images.where(post_id: id).first
  unless image_object.blank?
    image_id = image_object.id
    [image_id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead `image_id = Images.where(post_id: id).first`

Do

`image_id = Image.where(post_id: id).first`

You wrote wrong model name `Images`

> it's plural

while rails use

> singular form

for model name `Image`

**Note:** You have to set `id` value before this line

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
image_id.nil?
```

with

```
image_id.present? (As always to check object)
```